# Spring data cassandra support of schema sync for column family

Tags: java, spring-data-cassandra

I am able to create table using Spring data cassandra with configuration file extending AbstractCassandraConfiguration by overriding functions

```
@Override
public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
    return SchemaAction.RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;
}

@Override
public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
    return new String[] {"com.example"}; //com.example package contains the bean with @table annotation
}
```

but it creates table by dropping all the tables in keyspace first and then create tables. In the process, i lose the existing data that is in my table. I want to achieve something like SchemaSync: https://github.com/valchkou/cassandra-driver-mapping/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/mapping/schemasync/SchemaSync.java

So that, whenever there is change in my schema of column family like a new column is added, the table is updated with new column without deleting the existing entries in my table.

Answer (score 1):

This is the current state of the [SchemaAction](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/config/SchemaAction.java) enum which contains the available options:

```
public enum SchemaAction {

    /**
     * Take no schema actions.
     */
    NONE,

    /**
     * Create each table as necessary. Fail if a table already exists.
     */
    CREATE,

    /**
     * Create each table as necessary, dropping the table first if it exists.
     */
    RECREATE,

    /**
     * Drop <em>all</em> tables in the keyspace, then create each table as necessary.
     */
    RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;

    // TODO:
    // /**
    // * Validate that each required table and column exists. Fail if any required table or column does not exists.
    // */
    // VALIDATE,
    //
    // /**
    // * Alter or create each table and column as necessary, leaving unused tables and columns untouched.
    // */
    // UPDATE,
    //
    // /**
    // * Alter or create each table and column as necessary, removing unused tables and columns.
    // */
    // UPDATE_DROP_UNUNSED;
}
```

As you can see, the functionality that you ask for **is still not implemented**. Maybe you can contribute it to the project if you feel it is important.